# F# mutable with no initial value for MEF

Tags: f#, mef

I have a bunch of modules that export an IModule interface. So in the main program I have no problems

```
...
let mutable modules = Seq.empty
[<ImportMany>]
member x.Modules
    with get():IEnumerable<Lazy<IModule, IModuleData>> = modules
    and set(a) = modules <- a
...
```

But now I need to expose an interface back to those modules. So each module will import a single interface

```
...
let mutable parent:IParent = ?
[<Import>]
member x.Parent
    with get():IParent = parent
    and set(a) = parent <- a
...
```

So my problem is how do I go about creating my mutable "parent" when I have no initial value for it? Also, is this the appropriate way to expose an API back to component parts?

Comment: What about using `null`: let mutable parent:IParent = null?

Comment: I get a "The type 'IParent' does not have 'null' as a proper value" error

Comment: `null` = `Unchecked.defaultof<_>`

Comment: Thank you. That should be posted as the answer. let mutable parent = Unchecked.defaultof<IParent>. Not sure if it's gonna fully work, but it compiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let mutable parent = Unchecked.defaultof<IParent>
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 6):

Using `Unchecked.defaultof<_>` should do the trick, but it means that you're circumventing the F# type system, which may be a dangerous thing to do - the system tries to prevent you from accidentally dereferencing `null` values (and getting `NullReferenceException`).

Types that are declared in F# don't have `null` as a proper value, which is an attempt to eliminate the usual errors caused by `null`. The clean F# approach is to use option types to represent the fact that a value is missing:

```
let mutable parent:option<IParent> = None

[<Import>] 
member x.Parent 
   with get():IParent = 
      match parent with
      | Some p -> p
      | None -> failwith "TODO: Throw some reasonable exception here!"
   and set(a) = parent <- Some(a)
```

If you just want to say that `IParent` can have a `null` value (perhaps because you need to use it in some C# code that will ignore the F# restriction anyway), then you can mark the type definition using a special attribute that allows using `null` with the type.

```
[<AllowNullLiteral>]
type IParent = 
  abstract DoStuff : unit -> unit
```

Then you can write `let mutable parent:IParent = null`. The benefit of this approach is that you can also easily check whether a value is `null` (using just `if parent <> null then ...`) which is not that obvious when you use `Unchecked.defaultof<_>`.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on what Tomas explained, you should probably put your imports directly into your constructor. That will allow your code to be a bit more idiomatic.